# Libgdx - Couldn't load dependencies of asset

Tags: libgdx

I have a rather simple issue that's making me bang my head off my desk. My project is using the LibGdx framework and it's trying to load some assets. For some reason it doesn't see the assets within the correct folder.

Here's my assetmanager class

```java
public class LevelOneAssets {
    public static final String EARTH_TEXTURE = "earth.png";
    public static final String MARS_TEXTURE = "mars.png";

    private static AssetManager am;

    public static Class<Texture> TEXTURE = Texture.class;

    public static AssetManager load() {

        am = new AssetManager(new InternalFileHandleResolver());
        am.load(EARTH_TEXTURE, TEXTURE);
        am.load(MARS_TEXTURE, TEXTURE);
        am.update();
        return am;
    }
}
```

```java
private void init(){
    Gdx.app.log("GameScreen", "Initializing");
    isInitialized = true;
    am = LevelOneAssets.load();

    world = new World(new Vector2(0f, -9.8f), true);
    //Add Texture Component
    engine = new PooledEngine();

    RenderingSystem renderingSystem = new RenderingSystem(batch);
    engine.addSystem(new AnimationSystem());
    engine.addSystem(renderingSystem);
    engine.addSystem(new PhysicsSystem(world));

    engine.addSystem(new PhysicsDebugSystem(world, renderingSystem.getCamera()));
    engine.addSystem(new UselessStateSwapSystem());

    am.finishLoading();
    Entity e = buildEarth(world); // error here
    engine.addEntity(e);

    e = buildMars(world);
    engine.addEntity(e);
    engine.addEntity(buildFloorEntity(world));

    isInitialized = true;
}
```

All assets are within the `LauchOff/android/assets` directory. Any ideas? I am using Intellij and `gdxVersion = '1.9.6`.

EDIT ----

I updated the code but I am still getting `Couldn't load dependencies of asset: earth.png`. I got a feeling that this is an issue with my settings in Idea because I can run the code with gradle. Here's a screenshot of my idea settings. [image: Idea settings] There's not much that can go wrong...

Answer (score 3):

This is not the correct way to use AssetManager. You have two options.

1. Load everything synchronously on the game thread, waiting for it to finish. After you've queued everything, call `assetManager.finishLoading()` to completely load everything before returning.
2. Load asynchronously. This allows you to render something else and continue animating things while textures load on a background thread. After you've queued everything, call `assetManager.update()` continuously by putting the update call in the render loop. This method returns `true` when everything is done loading and it's safe to start getting your references to the loaded assets.

Off topic, but I recommend not using a static reference to your AssetManager as it is quite error prone to memory leaks and black textures. If you do this, make absolutely sure your game's `dispose()` method calls `dispose()` on the asset manager.

Answer (score 2):

Set *Working directory* with the path to your Asserts folder:

> C:\Projects\myFirstApp\android\assets

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtEg9.png)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `ExternalFileHandleResolver`, your resource are in your assets folder, so use `InternalFileHandleResolver` instead of `ExternalFileHandleResolver`. `ExternalFileHandleResolver` is used when resources are external (like pictures stored the user's phone).

```java
public static AssetManager load(){
    am = new AssetManager(new InternalFileHandleResolver());
    am.load(EARTH_TEXTURE, TEXTURE);
    am.load(MARS_TEXTURE, TEXTURE);
    am.finishLoading();  //Load everything synchronously otherwise make continuous call of update() method  
    return am;
}
```